# How can I find the pages that belong to the heap in a linux process?

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I would like to write a simple kernel function that iterates over all the `vm_area_struct`s that belong to a specific process and mark each one of them as belonging to the heap or not. Assume that I can add a boolean field in the `vm_area_struct` that will be set for heap pages and reset for other pages.

I have looked into the `mm_struct`, `vm_area_struct`, and `task_struct`... but found nothing that can help.

**Update: I am guessing start_brk and brk have something to do with this?**

Comment: Define what you exactly mean by heap. Look at `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/$(pidof app)/maps` for some Linux application.

Comment: I am referring to the part of memory where malloc() gets the memory from. For this, is there more than one region?

Comment: @hebbo : I'm not sure that the os has this information...

Comment: I think there should be a way. Since malloc() under the hood calls the OS to give it more memory using either mmap() or sbrk(). The OS also loads the process into memory and marks the bss, code and other segments.

Comment: As @BasileStarynkevitch points out, the OS already implements /proc/<pid>/maps which shows all VMAs of that process, including the heap and of course the mmap-ed ones. Why not check out its code? (Right now I don't have access to the codebase).

Comment: Wrt my prev comment:
the relevant code seems to be here: fs/proc/task_mmu.c

And, yes indeed, the "[heap]" is marked by this code snippet from the abv src file (kernel ver 3.10.24):

<code>
...
    if (vma->vm_start <= mm->brk &&
            vma->vm_end >= mm->start_brk) {
            name = "[heap]";
            goto done;
        }
...
</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Am inserting my last comment as an answer, as the formatting within "Comment" is not that great):*

Wrt my prev comment: the relevant code (to look up VMAs of a given PID) seems to be here: **fs/proc/task_mmu.c** .

And, yes indeed, the "[heap]" is marked by this code snippet from the above src file (kernel ver 3.10.24):

*fs/proc/task_mmu.c:show_map_vma()*
 
`... 
if (vma->vm_start <= mm->brk && 
    vma->vm_end >= mm->start_brk) { 
    name = "[heap]"; 
    goto done; } 
...`